# Infinite Horizontal Scrolling Pattern/Images with fixed position

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Ive tried to have a function (see below) for Infinite Horizontal Scrolling Pattern/Images with fixed position. The Infinite Scrolling function works, but **my only problem is the fixed position**.

I wanted to give that infinite Horizontal Scrolling Image a fixed position, meaning that if i scroll down the website, the image should stay on position and should scroll horizontaly at the same time.

I've tried to add a `"position:fixed;"` or `"background-attachment: fixed"` under the css class selectors but it does not work, instead of functioning, the image disappear.

Url: https://codepen.io/Founts/pen/dXkyAa

```css
.hero {
  height: 300px;
}

.hero-img {
  background: transparent url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/50859/bit-tile-blue.gif) repeat-x 50% 0;
  animation: infinite-shift-left 5000s linear;
  
}

@keyframes infinite-shift-left {
  0% {
    background-position: 50000px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero hero-img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `position: fixed;` removes the element from the document flow, the `<div>` does not automatically fill the width of the screen. To fix this, give it a `width`:

```
.hero {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: @M.a.mu If one of these answers fixed your issue please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

to your `.hero` class